# wrf_chemi file with 30 time steps

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, numerical-modelling, wrf, wrf-chem

I creat wrfchemi file for my wrf-chem, my wrfchemi file has 30 time step,
**frames_per_auxinput5**     = **30,   30,**
auxinput5_inname         = "wrfchemi_d*",
auxinput5_interval_m     = **60,  60,**
**frames_per_auxinput7**     = **30,    30,**
io_form_auxinput5        = 2,
auxinput7_inname         = "wrffirechemi_d*",
auxinput7_interval_m     = **60,  60,**
io_form_auxinput7       = 2,

when I run ./wrf.exe, I face with this error:

3  input_wrf: wrf_get_next_time current_date: 2010-07-16_18:00:00 Status =          -11
At line 1008 of file input_wrf.f90
Fortran runtime error: End of record
my name list.input:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18vePBFOk-zrq761ex1siJ7KDF1x8CGif/view?usp=sharing
my rsl.error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/129FuD4f7g8FIRhVykfrRm5BY-dDrDEWo/view?usp=sharing
my wrfchemifile:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dDJ8JheDhyRnBHDOX5Xzqg5vb2quVO3F/view?usp=sharing
could you please help me to sole this error and run the mode?
thank you very much in deed

Comment: You need to change the access for the Google Drive. What emissions inventory are you using? Have you changed the convert_emiss.F file to fit that inventory?

Comment: No I didn't change convert_emiss.F. I have made the wrfchemi file by my self, I create it in netcdf format that will be suitable for wrf

Comment: by the way I changed the access for google drive

Comment: you can check it now dear BarocliniCplusplus

Comment: when I put (frames_per_auxinput5 = 1, 1, auxinput5_inname = "wrfchemi_d", auxinput5_interval_m = 3600, 3600, frames_per_auxinput7 = 1, 1, io_form_auxinput5 = 2, auxinput7_inname = "wrffirechemi_d", auxinput7_interval_m = 3600, 3600, io_form_auxinput7 = 2,)  it will run but when I put 30 and 60 it doesn't run.

Comment: What the rsl output is saying is that it fails when trying to read the first domain emissions file. But from your post, I gather that you don't have an emissions file for your first domain, do you?

Comment: I have, but I only download the second domain.but now I put the link of wrfchemi_d01:https://drive.google.com/file/d/14QuV-QYOaaONjQzZRdll1HW8MaI3ZmUS/view?usp=sharing